# Is there a way to run a raw JOIN with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to run a raw JOIN with sequelize?

Below is an example query. I can't use a JOIN directly because the table b can contain multiple records from table a based on each group_id. I am running a WHERE id IN (subquery) which turns out to be slow for large datasets. A JOIN is performing better when compared. However, I don't see an option within sequelize to do a raw INNER JOIN.

```
TABLE A
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |     John Doe     |
|---------------------|------------------|


TABLE B
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |        a_id      |     group_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         12       |       415        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         12       |       416        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         12       |       417        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT b.a_id FROM b WHERE b.group_id IN (1,2,4,5,6)) as b ON b.a_id = a.id
ORDER BY a.updated_at DESC;
```

Comment: Did you try with `include`?

Comment: I have tried. It wont let me join a raw sql query. Other joins work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a sub-query using sequelize literal and it worked out fine for the most part. A year later now I have created a separate field as group_id in all tables and moved all permissions data into them. The join / sub-query was too expensive in our use case.

Answer (score 0):

On the core sequelize allows 2 joins with keyword `required` in include

1. required:true[default] translates to INNER JOIN.
2. required:false translates to LEFT OUTER JOIN.

> Reference for the same:
> https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

I don't think sequelize has anything that fits your usage, try using raw query(if you think your query is optimized):

Code snippet from official docs:

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = ?',
  {
    replacements: ['active'],
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);

await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = :status',
  {
    replacements: { status: 'active' },
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);
```

> References for the same:
> https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html